# EnumWindows can not enumerate UAC window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am currently building application which performs some unattended automated tests on some hardware equipment. It executes a bunch of .msi installers and then performs tests on them.

Here is the execution environment:
- Windows 7 Standard Embedded
- UAC turned on - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA` is set to 1

I use combination of `EnumWindows()`/`EnumChildWindows()` Win32 API calls to detect windows with specific captions, their child windows such as buttons, edit boxes...etc. Then some tasks are automated by sending keystrokes and mouse clicks via Win32 call `SendMessage()`.

This works great until UAC dialog box pops up. Then it seems that user must type the Administrator password manually. Our application is aware of Administrator credentials and is supposed to use them when this situation arises.

The question is this. Is it possible to enumerate UAC window (when it is on of course) via `EnumWindows()` call at all?
Our routine which scans for various window captions is executed every 3 seconds on main gui thread. But UAC window is never detected.

My workaround was to run .msi installer using `CreateProcessWithLogonW()` call. With Administrator credentials as parameters this of course worked and UAC box never popped up.
However, this was not accepted by the customer. :(

Customer wants UAC box to pop up and it being filled programatically with Administrator credentials, with no user interaction.
I have no idea how to achieve this or whether it is even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Customer is foolish and has rejected the correct solution.

Comment: May as well just turn off UAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UAC dialogs are shown on a different desktop, the secure desktop. Your standard user won't be able to automate that secure desktop. So I don't think it's going to be possible.

I believe that you can disable the secure desktop and have the UAC dialogs shown on the interactive desktop but of course that's a large security hole.

Comment: [Turn off the secure desktop in Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/975788)

Comment: Good suggestions guys, thanks. But unfortunately, I'm not allowed to make any configuration changes to Windows. There are quite a few of those machines with the same restrictive config.
And as you know, calling secpol.msc or writing anything to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE requires Administrator credentials anyway.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it.